# package.json not installing a devDependencies

Tags: git, github, npm, package.json

I'm trying to `npm install` and in the `package.json` is the following line:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@ff0000-ad-tech/ad-docs": "git+https://github.com/ff0000-ad-tech/ad-docs.git"
    }
```

No matter what I try - various SSH syntax, or HTTP, etc - the package never installs. I *can* install it directly by writing `npm install https://github.com/ff0000-ad-tech/ad-docs.git` in my terminal, and it installs without prompts for credentials because I have my system set up that way. However, no combination of organizing my package.json will get the **ad-docs** package to install.

I've tried other packages in the ff0000-ad-tech library, and they all install just fine. It's only this one.

I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution or asking the correct question to properly Google the solution.

This particular **ad-docs** package is *not* on NPM, I'm just trying to download directly from GitHub.

Any suggestions or solutions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any errors during `npm install` ? Did you try a clean install by deleting your `node_modules` folder ?

Comment: @felixyadomi There are no errors. All I see in the terminal is " @ff0000-ad-tech/ad-docs@1.2.2 checking installable status" without any follow up information and I've deleted node_modules / package-lock repeatedly. Even moving from "devDependencies" to just "dependencies" and strippping all other packages yields the same result: no installation :/

Comment: Did you try with https only instead of git+https ?

Comment: @felixyadomi indeed I have